# Should I set title with .prop or .attr

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw a comment saying

> It'd be better to set the "title" property with `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` if you're using at least version 1.6 of jQuery.

Can someone explain why this is?

Comment: "The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes."

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5876747/545858

Comment: I think in this case `.prop` vs `.attr` doesn't matter due to how the title property and attribute behaves. If you update one, the other gets updated. In the 1.6.1 release blog post (http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/), it was listed in the table as `.attr()` being the preferred method for title, but no explanation as to why was given.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you're familiar with the [differences between `prop` and `attr`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5874652/1048572).

As the [`title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#the-title-attribute) is [reflected](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-dom-interfaces.html#reflect) by the `title` property, there is actually no difference.

Comment: If I set with .attr will it be visible when I check the HTML code using firebug or another debugger. If so I see this as an advantage.

Comment: As I said, they will be reflected - if you set the `.title` property, the DOM (which you inspect with Firebug) should change as well - the inspector's view might need a reload

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

`prop` is used for getting properties of HTML objects

`attr` is used for getting atttributes.

The [prop documentation from jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) explains it quite well.

Comment: I realize the above but I saw one of the posters here say it was better to use .prop for the title. Just wondering why that was said.